# Teradata Insert Error: ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous

Tags: pandas, teradata

I am trying to insert a pandas dataframe into Teradata and running into this error. The connection to Teradata is working as I was able to insert the same data one record at a time. Please help.

```
import pandas as pd
import teradata as td

Car_Sales = pd.DataFrame([
    {"Sale_Dt":"2019-10-01", "Brand":"Mercedes","Sale_Type":"New","Dealer_Type":"Urban","SalesVol":"5"},
    {"Sale_Dt":"2019-10-02", "Brand":"BMW","Sale_Type":"Used","Dealer_Type":"Sub-Urban","SalesVol":"3"},
    ])

udaExec = td.UdaExec()
with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",DSN = "dsn1",driver = 'Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20') as session:
#session.execute("INSERT INTO db.tbl_Cars (Sale_Dt,Brand,Sale_Type,Dealer_Type,SalesVol) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",("2019-10-01","Mercedes","New","Urban",5))
query2 = "INSERT INTO db.tbl_Cars"    
session.execute(query2,Car_Sales,batch=True)
```

Error:
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: Why not use pandas' `to_sql` method? Also consider using `teradatasqlalchemy` package for that instead of `teradata` package plus ODBC.

Comment: I can try in the next iterations of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably because you are directly passing a DataFrame to `execute`.  Also, for batch insert, the documentation says that you have to use `executemany`.
A small example -

```
session.executemany("""INSERT INTO employee (id, firstName, lastName, dob) 
                       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)""", 
                    ((1,"James", "Kirk", "2233-03-22"), 
                     (2,"Jean-Luc", "Picard", "2305-07-13")), 
                    batch=True)
```

So, in your case, it would be

```
with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",DSN = "dsn1",driver = 'Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20') as session:
    #session.execute("INSERT INTO db.tbl_Cars (Sale_Dt,Brand,Sale_Type,Dealer_Type,SalesVol) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)",("2019-10-01","Mercedes","New","Urban",5))

    #No. of ? must be equal to number of fields in each tuple 
    query2 = "INSERT INTO db.tbl_Cars VALUES (?, ?, ...)" 

    data = tuple(tuple(x) for x in Car_Sales.values)
    session.executemany(query2, data, batch=True)
```

For more info, check out the documentation of [teradata](https://downloads.teradata.com/tools/reference/teradata-python-module#ExecuteParameters)

Comment: Same error. ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()